# How to upload Excel File(data) with progress bar in jQuery ajax and asp.net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

```
 <div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">0%</div>
 </div>
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PassData([FromBody] List<Model> models)
{
foreach (var item in models)
{
 //data iteration
}
}
```

Comment: You could check this link:https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Pages/StreamedSingleFileUploadDb.cshtml

Comment: Has no progress bar

Comment: I would deliver you the demo with process bar tomorrow

Comment: I will appreciate that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="uploadFile" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" id="uplodsss">
</form>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="uploadFile_progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60"
         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em;">
        <span id="uploadFile_rate">0%</span>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#uplodsss").click(function () {
           
            $('#uploadFile').ajaxSubmit({
                type: 'post',
                url: "Upload",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                resetForm: true,
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    if (percentComplete > 100) {
                        percentComplete = 100;
                    }
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    $("#uploadFile_rate").html(percentVal);
                    $("#uploadFile_progressBar").width(percentVal);

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                    $("#uploadFile_progressBar").width("0px");
                    $("#uploadFile_rate").html("0%");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```